# Добавление блока текста справа относительно блока, который увеличивается. CSS

Tags: css

Созданы блоки, которые увеличиваются при наведении мышки на блок с помощью метода :hover. Хотел бы добавить чтоб справа добавлялся текст, но пока что не выходит. Подскажите как правильно это оформить.

```
style: 
.jumbotron4:hover 
{ position: relative;
opacity: 1; 
transform: scale(1.38);
transition: all .4s ease-out;}

html:
<div1 class="jumbotron4">
                <div class="jumb5">
                    <img src="{{ goods.image.url }}">
                </div>
                <p1>Цена: {{ goods.price }} ₽</p1>
</div1>
```

Comment: Павел, добавьте исходный код для контекста

Comment: `.jumbotron4 > p { display: none; } .jumbotron4:hover p { display: block; }`, вот и всё.

Comment: Как отрегулировать, чтоб блок появлялся справа, а не под или над?

Comment: Все, понял как именно делается, спасибо.